# How to call a webservice with Parameters in Android?

Tags: android, web-services, parameters, android-asynctask

I am new to android development. I know how to call webservice in iOS but when it comes to android I am blank. I have read many answer to it and they suggest different approaches. I have main activity and one Webservice class which extends AsynTask class. I want to call a webservice with URL "http://myURL.com/login" with two parameters **email** and **password**. but I dont understand where I have to pass parameters and from where I can add it to URLConnection. I know it's a very basic question but I have already lost 5 hours in it.

my **MainActivity class**:

```
WebService webService = new WebService(this,"http://myURL.com/login","xyz@test.com","123456");

webService.execute();
```

my **WebService class**

```
 protected String  doInBackground(String... params) {

    /************ Make Post Call To Web Server ***********/
    BufferedReader reader=null;

    // Send data
    try
    {

        // Defined URL  where to send data
        URL url = new URL(urlString);

        // Send POST data request

        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

        wr.write( data );
        wr.flush();

        wr.close();
        // Get the server response

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        // Read Server Response
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            // Append server response in string
            sb.append(line + " ");
        }

        // Append Server Response To Content String
        Content = sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Error = ex.getMessage();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {

            reader.close();
        }

        catch(Exception ex) {}
    }

    /*****************************************************/
    return null;

}
```

Comment: Try Retrofit... Its easily configurable

Comment: I dont wnat to use third party, Is there any way to do it by using android internal libraries?

Comment: Do you know where to pass these parameters I meant whether in header or in url?

Comment: It is a simple post service. So I have to pass in URL

Comment: this tutorial might help you: [link](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-java-web-service-login/)

Comment: check this : https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Answer (score 2):

If you wan't use third party, you can follow this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-making-http-requests/), hopefully can help you guys :)